# What packages do I install for ffmpeg and libmp3lame?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

On my desktop Ubuntu 10.4 I use ffmpeg to convert videos to a format my dvd-player understands. On my laptop running 10.10 I can't get the same command to work, what package(s) are missing?

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flv \
-threads 2 -vcodec mpeg4 -vtag divx -acodec libmp3lame \
outfile.avi

#...snip
Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
```

Using `apt-cache search libmp3lame` I'm told there exist libmp3lame0 and libmp3lame-dev, both of which I've installed. Using `acodec libmp3lame0` doesn't work either.

Comment: Why didn't you `sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0` ?

Comment: @marco I did: *"...both of which I've installed"*.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-52`

If package not found try:

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53`

you can also try to install the `libmp3lame0` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0
```

Comment: I tried "sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-52" Everything got install correctly But, still doesn't work, ffmpeg unable to find the **libmp3lame** or **libmp3lame0**

Answer (score 8):

Install the encoder by running he following command

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Open Synaptic Package Manager and reinstall ffmpeg.
Also try installing winff in Synaptic, this will give you a GUI for ffmpeg.
Edit...
See also http://code.google.com/p/winff/wiki/UbuntuInstallation about adding "libavcodec-extra-52, libavutil-extra-49 and libavformat-extra-52 from the multiverse repository"

Comment: Thank you so much,
It works now!, This link [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095][1] has explained the complete installation.
  [1]: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095